# How to properly write a javaScript toggle hide/show function for 2 forms (Registration and Login form) without refreshing a page or link to new html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, toggle, event-listener

I went through all similar questions but none of them seem to help me with what I want to do. Maybe I am just missing something and if there is a question out there that could help could you please point me to that question and I will delete this. Anywhoo...
I am trying to create a function that when I click a link on the bottom of the login form (Need an account? Register) it will hide the Login form and show the Registration form with a link on the bottom of the Registration form (Have an account? Login) to go back to the Login form without refreshing the page or going to a new html page.
I have tried multiple things... I want it to look like this... I have set the display to none for my registration form and the display for my login form to block.
[example of login to registration and back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFJrZ.png)

This is two of the codes I have tried.

Example one that seems right but is wrong:

```
function showAndHide() {
   const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginbtn');
   const signupBtn = document.getElementById('signupbtn');
   const regForm = document.getElementById('register');
   const logForm = document.getElementById('login');
   if (regForm.style.display == 'none') {
       regForm.style.display = 'block';
       logForm.style.display = 'none';
   } else {
       logForm.style.display = 'block';
       regForm.style.display = 'none';
}
loginBtn.addEventListener('onclick', function() {
showAndHide(loginBtn);
});
signupBtn.addEventListener('onclick', function() {
showAndHide(signupBtn);
});
```

Example two that seems right but is wrong:

```
function showAndHide() {
  const regForm = document.getElementById('register');
  const logForm = document.getElementById('login');
  if (regForm.style.display = 'none') {
      regForm.style.display = 'block';
      logForm.style.display = 'none';
  } else { 
      logForm.style.display = 'none';
      regForm.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

My Html:

```
 <body>
<section id="login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="login-form" method="post" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="logfield">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="logfield" id="logfield" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
           <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" id="signupbtn">Need an account? Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<section id="register">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form id="register-form" method="post" no validate>
        <div>
            <label for="email-field2">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email-field2" id="email-field2" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw2">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw2" id="pw2" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pw3">Repeat Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pw3" id="pw3" size="15" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">REGISTER</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" id="loginbtn">Have an account? Log in</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
```